NodeJS Redis Proxy/Routing
Is it possible on Nodejs to organize kind of proxy for a Redis connection which would simply rewrite incoming request keys.
The basic idea is to separate/isolate a Data Space for a set of clients on a single Redis instance with kind of perfixing their keys (16 instances is not a solution here)
At the very high level it seems to be as simple as
const shardPrefix = 'some-prefix/'

const server = net.createServer((client) => {
  const redisClient = redis.createClient({...})

  clientSocket.on('data', (data) => {
    const [command, key, ...args] = data.toString().split(' ')

    const rewrittenKey = shardPrefix + key

    // Forward command and rewritten key to Redis server
    redisClient
       .sendCommand(command, [rewrittenKey, ...args])
       .then((reply) => {
            clientSocket.write(reply.toString())
       });
  });

  clientSocket.on('end', () => {
    redisClient.quit()
  })
})

server.listen(proxyPort)

Still to be sure this have any chance to work

Is it correct to expect that all Redis commands have the same format as command key ...rest

would it really work on a such a simple socket streaming or does Redis have any proper protocol for this?

On a second thought it seems that even some responses must be patched as well (e.g. KEYS *. Are there any more)

Is there maybe a ready solution for this

Or maybe this is achievable simply on a native Redis implementation level it self or its nodejs client


Thanks
